# Internal Server Error Ajax Laravel

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel

I'm using laravel 4 and I'm trying to send a request to the controller using ajax when I click the link:

**html:**

```
<a class='btn btn-primary signup ' id="btnDialog"
 onClick='ajouter({{$data->id_facture}});'> Ajouter à la lise de paiement</a>
```

but I always get the error post 500 (Internal Server Error)

**javascript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function ajouter(id){

    $.ajax({

        url:'/ajouter/'+id,
        dataType: 'JSON',
        type: 'post',

        success:function(data){

        if(data == 'ok'){
            alert('added to the  list');
        } else {
            alert('error');
        }
    }
    });
    return false;
}

</script>
```

**controller:**

```
public function ajouter($id=0){

    //return json_encode('ok');
    if($facture = Facture::find($id))
    {
        $item = new List($id);
        Session::put('list',$item);
        return json_encode('ok');
    }
    else
        return json_encode('error');
}
```

**By the way, I made a simple test with the following code and it's working:**

**javascript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function ajouter(id){

    $.ajax({

        url:'/ajouter/'+id,
        dataType: 'JSON',
        type: 'post',

        success:function(data){

            console.log(data);
        }
    });

    return false;
}

</script>
```

**controller:**

```
public function ajouter($id=0)
{
    return json_encode('ok');
}
```

Comment: try to check WHAT error message you get on your 500 status. Maybe it will help you to recognize what is the problem. You can do this with the help of Network tab in Developer tools in browser

Comment: In your `ajax` you are passing the id in the `url`, but I can not see that you are getting this Id in your controller, so when you are trying to fetch your record this will not succeed.

Answer (score 0):

Your ajax request

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/ajouter',      
  type: 'GET',
  data: "id=" + id,
  dataType: "JSON",
  success: function(data,  textStatus, jqXHR)
  {  
    if(data !="")
    {               
      console.log(data);            
    }

  },
  error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
  {             
    //alert();
  }
});
```

This is your controller

```
public function getAjouter()
{
  $id = Input::get('id');
  $facture = Facture::find($id);
  if(count($facture) > 0)
  {  
    $item = new List($id);
    Session::put('list', $item);
    return json_encode('ok');
  }
  else {
    return Response::json(array('error' => 'Error message'), 401);
  }
}
```